# Finding list of versions available in a Maven repository for a specific plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-metadata

Given the following repository URL from my pom.xml how can I determine what the latest versions of spring and hibernate are available in the repository?
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programatically or just manually?

Since the repository works over HTTP you can just navigate it manually:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate/
http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/

Answer (score 24):

Retrieve the `maven-metadata.xml` file, placed in the artifact directory, e.g. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/media/jai_codec/maven-metadata.xml for an artifact with the groupId `com.sun.media` and artifactId `jai_codec`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<metadata>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>0.0.5</latest>
    <release>0.0.5</release>

    <versions>
      <version>0.0.3</version>
      <version>0.0.4</version>
      <version>0.0.5</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20090725212606</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>

</metadata>
```

Comment: How I can get URL to maven plugin in automatic way (from command line)?

Answer (score 2):

As Robert's answer says, the maven-metadata.xml file for each artifact in the repository holds the version information you need. In particular note the **latest** and **release** elements in the metadata. The latest element denotes the last version to be published, this may not be the version you want though. For example it could be a maintenance release to an older version, a release candidate, or a milestone. The release version denotes the last published version intended to be treated as a release, so generally you'd want to take this version.

For information the [Maven super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) has a special **release-profile** profile, activated by setting the *performRelease* property (e.g. by passing -DperformRelease on the command line). Amongst other things, activating this property will set the *updateReleaseInfo* property of the deploy-plugin so that the metadata will be updated when you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the real use case is, it can be worth looking at  http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/