# Listing all Versions of an Artifact via Command Line

Tags: maven, command-line

Including all versions installed to ~/.m2, and deployed to maven or an artifact repository like artifactory.

For example, if I type something like this make believe command:

```
mvn ver:show-all -DartifactId=myProject -DallowSnapshots=true
```

I hope to see some output listing available versions:

```
myProject ->
  0.9
  1.0.1
  1.1-branchA-SNAPSHOT
  1.1-branchB-SNAPSHOT
  1.1-branchC-SNAPSHOT
```

Is there a maven plugin which does this today?

Comment: I don't think there is a Maven plugin to do that. This might be of interest though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374064/1743880

Comment: Yes, this should really be Maven's feature. But it's not there and people are forced to some [ugly Ruby hacks involving Nexus REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31011010/122727)

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is look at [Maven Repository Metadata Model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-repository-metadata/). It's basically and XML file that you can download and parse. For example, to know all the versions of Google Guice available in Maven Central download repository metadata, available at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/maven-metadata.xml and look at its content:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>4.2.2</latest>
    <release>4.2.2</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <version>2.0-no_aop</version>
      <version>3.0-rc2</version>
      <version>3.0-rc3</version>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <version>4.0-beta</version>
      <version>4.0-beta4</version>
      <version>4.0-beta5</version>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
      <version>4.2.1</version>
      <version>4.2.2</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20181029173633</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

You'll see all the versions!

Though, it's not a 100% complete solution:

- There may be newer (other) version(s) in other repositories. E.g. if one syncs JARs from Bintray to Maven Central Bintray can contain the JARs not available in Central. Though, they seem to be the same for [Guice](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/download_file?file_path=com%2Fgoogle%2Finject%2Fguice%2Fmaven-metadata.xml).
- There may be no `maven-metadata.xml`. E.g. if you're using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/#google/guice/4.2.1) or repos hosted on S3.

Comment: Yikes. That's not what I would call... user friendly. Thanks for the answer though.